# What is Monero Direct?

Tags: fiat

What is Monero Direct?

- What payment methods are accepted?
- Who runs it?
- What are the fees?
- What personal information is required to purchase Monero?

Please provide both a basic description and an in depth description of the type found on [Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@JustinEU4's answer is pretty good. But to expand on a few details:

1) The site is currently in beta test and this is not the final form of the web site. We are looking for additional payment processors and payment methods to add still. We are focusing on fiat currency methods. We assume if you already own Bitcoin or other cryptocurrencies then you don't need our help to buy Monero.

2) I am one of the company directors. The company owner is an established businessman / entrepreneur doing business for over 20 years in Ireland.

3) OKPAY lists their fees as 0% for these transactions. If you compare their Euro-BTC exchange rate to current rates on common exchanges, it looks like they are taking 5% in the Euro to BTC conversion, and they charge an explicit 1% on their payment checkout page.

4) On an unverified OKPAY account, you have a 300 Euro spending limit. OKPAY sends us everything it knows about you as a customer, however we ignore most of it. (The items sent include your full name and address, phone number, and OKPAY reputation score.) The only thing we parse is your email address, for sending you a transaction confirmation email. We don't store any of your personal details - once the transaction confirmation email is sent, all of your personal information is discarded.

Answer (score 5):

> What payment methods are accepted?

MoneroDirect uses OKPAY, which accepts a large number of payment types found on [this page](https://www.okpay.com/en/business/accepting-payments/). This includes Bitcoin, Litecoin, MasterCard, VISA, Webmoney, and others.

> Who runs it?

The website's [About page](https://monerodirect.com/aboutUs.php) is currently blank. However, it appears to be at least partially supported by /u/hyc_symas, as seen on the [Reddit post here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/594q89/monerodirectcom_public_beta_test_begins/).

> What are the fees?

The fees include OKPAY's fee, the Poloniex fee, and the Monero transaction fees. According to /u/hyc_symas, the total fees are about 9%, with OKPAY taking about 5% and MoneroDirect taking about 4% ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/594q89/monerodirectcom_public_beta_test_begins/d9697kw/?context=1)). See specific OKPAY fees [here](https://www.okpay.com/en/personal/fees/).

> What personal information is required to purchase Monero?

From what I can tell, MoneroDirect does not require any information about you. However, keep in mind that MoneroDirect will learn what account the money is being sent to (so if the account is used somewhere else, it could reveal the owner of the account) and the OKPAY will know all the information about you that it asks you to provide. For instance, if you provide your home address to OKPAY, then that home address can be linked to your Monero account. On [OKPAY's sign up page](https://secure.okpay.com/en/account/signup.html), it asks for a first name, last name, phone number, and email.